# How to make a transfer function in oop

Tags: python, oop

Hello guys i want to ask you about how should i make a transfer function for example i want to transfer money .I have two variables bank = BankAccount and i want to transfer money to them if accountNumber for example is not correct I want to print this account number didn't exist can you help me about this idea thank you a lot.Here's what i tried by far and tell me if code is good or i could change something ,Thank you a lot!

```
import time
import datetime
class BankSystem:
    total_deposit = 0
    total_withdraw = 0
    def __init__(self,name,accountNumber,born,salary):
        self.name = name
        self.accountNumber = accountNumber
        self.born = born
        self.salary = salary
        self.withdraw_history = []
        self.deposit_history = []
        self.account_list = []
    def description(self):
        print("Name is: " , self.name)
        print("AccountNumber: " , self.accountNumber)
        print("Salary: " , self.salary)
    def deposit(self,deposit):
        self.salary = self.salary + deposit 
        self.deposit_history.append(deposit)
        self.total_deposit += 1
    def withdraw(self,withdraw):
        self.salary = self.salary - withdraw
        self.withdraw_history.append(deposit)
        self.total_withdraw += 1
    def transaction_history(self):
        print("You have withdraw", self.withdraw_history , "On date:" , datetime.datetime.now())
        print("You have deposit" , self.deposit_history , "On date:" , datetime.datetime.now())
    def take_loan(self):
        answer = int(input("Enter the amount of loan who would you like to take between - 100Euros and 300 Euros: "))
        if answer > 300:
            print("Choose between 100 - 300 Euros not more")
        else:
            print("You have taken out for loan, you will pay extra 1.5 from that sum" , answer * 1.5)
    def open_account(self):
        self.account_list.append(self.name)
        self.account_list.append(self.accountNumber)
        self.account_list.append(self.born)
    def see_account(self):
            print("New Account list" , self.account_list)
    
        
        
bank = BankSystem("Bill" , 42919502 , "Massachutes" , 4000)
bank = BankSystem("John" , 30503202104 , "Cardiff" , 4000)
bank.open_account()
bank.see_account()
```

Comment: I think you are mixing two concepts here, the accounts and the banking system itself. When you instantiate the John Cardiff account you override the previous one (you'll ever have a single account in your bank system for now if I read that correctly)

Comment: you want to say that i have two bank variables from BankSystem and i should change to bank1 and bank2 for example ?

Comment: Yep, to me it seems your object is more of an "bankAccount" one, you'll need another object that could handle transaction between multiple bankAccounts and that would be your BankSystem

Comment: you should have two variables `bank1` and `bank2`and then you can transfer using `bank1.deposit( bank2.withdraw() )`  (but better names could be `account1`, `account2` and `account1.deposit( account2.withdraw() )`)

Comment: Can you write that  code and give me because i don't understand that well

Comment: Check out @furas comment, I think it might be enough for your case ;) I may have thought too much about it  -_-

Comment: frankly, your class is mix of two classes `Bank` and `Account`. Strange is also `salary` in this class. It should be class `Account` without `account_list` and `open_account` and `see_account`

Comment: instead of description, why not __repr__?

Comment: intsead of  self.withdraw_history.append(deposit) you could do self.withdraw_history.append(withdrawl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make transfer you have to assign every person to separated variable

```
account1 = BankSystem("Bill", 42919502, "Massachutes", 4000)

account2 = BankSystem("John", 30503202104, "Cardiff", 4000)

# transfer 100 from Bill to John
value = 100
account1.withdraw(value)
account2.deposit(value)

print('---')

account1.description()

print('---')

account2.description()

print('---')
```

Result:

```
---
Name is:  Bill
AccountNumber:  42919502
Salary:  3900
---
Name is:  John
AccountNumber:  30503202104
Salary:  4100
---
```

---

But I would rather named this class `Account` and I would remove `account_list`, `open_account`, `see_account` or move it to class `Bank`.

```
import datetime

class Account:

    def __init__(self, name, number, born, money=0):
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
        self.born = born
        self.money = money

        self.number_of_deposits = 0
        self.number_of_withdraws = 0
        
        self.history = []
        
    def description(self):
        print("Name is: " , self.name)
        print("Account Number: " , self.number)
        print("Money: " , self.money)
        
    def deposit(self, value):
        self.money += value
        self.history.append(value)
        self.number_of_deposits += 1
        return True
    
    def withdraw(self, value):
        if self.money < value:
            print(f'{self.name} no enought money')
            return False
        
        self.money -= value
        self.history.append(-value)
        self.number_of_withdraws += 1
        return True
    
    def transaction_history(self):
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        print("You have withdraw", self.number_of_withdraws , "On date:" , today)
        print("You have deposit" , self.number_of_deposits  , "On date:" , today)
        
    def take_loan(self):
        answer = int(input("Enter the amount of loan who would you like to take between - 100Euros and 300 Euros: "))
        if answer > 300:
            print("Choose between 100 - 300 Euros not more")
        else:
            print("You have taken out for loan, you will pay extra 1.5 from that sum" , answer * 1.5)
    
class Bank:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_accounts = {}
        
    def open_account(self, name, account_number, born, money):
        account = Account(name, account_number, born, money)
        self.all_accounts[account_number] = account
    
    def show_accounts(self, show_history=False):
        for number, account in self.all_accounts.items():
            print('\n---', number, '---\n')
            account.description()
            if show_history:
                print('History:', account.history)
            
    def transfer(self, account_number1, account_number2, value):
        # check if it can withdraw
        if self.all_accounts[account_number1].withdraw(value):
            self.all_accounts[account_number2].deposit(value)
     
    def get_account(self, number):
        return self.all_accounts[number]
                                      
# --- main ---        
        
bank = Bank()
bank.open_account("Bill", 42919502, "Massachutes", 4000)
bank.open_account("John", 30503202104, "Cardiff", 4000)

print('\n===== before =====\n')
bank.show_accounts(show_history=True)

bank.transfer(42919502, 30503202104, 100)
bank.transfer(42919502, 30503202104, 300)
bank.transfer(30503202104, 42919502, 500)

print('\n===== after =====\n')
bank.show_accounts(show_history=True)
```

Result:

```
===== before =====


--- 42919502 ---

Name is:  Bill
Account Number:  42919502
Money:  4000
History: []

--- 30503202104 ---

Name is:  John
Account Number:  30503202104
Money:  4000
History: []

===== after =====


--- 42919502 ---

Name is:  Bill
Account Number:  42919502
Money:  4100
History: [-100, -300, 500]

--- 30503202104 ---

Name is:  John
Account Number:  30503202104
Money:  3900
History: [100, 300, -500]
```

---

**EDIT:**

Eventually you could use normal `dictionary` instead of `Account` but then you would have to move functions from `Account` to `Bank` and use `account_number` as first argument

```
import datetime

class Bank:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_accounts = {}
        
    def open_account(self, name, account_number, born, money):
        account = {
            'name': name,
            'number': account_number,
            'born': born,
            'money': money,
            'number_of_deposits': 0,
            'number_of_withdraws': 0,
            'history': []
        }
        self.all_accounts[account_number] = account
    
    def show_accounts(self, show_history=False):
        for number, account in self.all_accounts.items():
            print('\n---', number, '---\n')
            self.description(number)
            if show_history:
                print('History:', account['history'])
            
    def transfer(self, account_number1, account_number2, value):
        # check if it can withdraw
        if self.withdraw(account_number1, value):
            self.deposit(account_number2, value)
     
    def get_account(self, number):
        return self.all_accounts[number]

    # -- from Account, need account_number as first argument ---
    
    def description(self, number):
        account = self.get_account(number)
        print("Name is: " , account['name'])
        print("Account Number: " , account['number'])
        print("Money: " , account['money'])
        
    def deposit(self, number, value):
        account = self.get_account(number)
        account['money'] += value
        account['history'].append(value)
        account['number_of_deposits'] += 1
        return True
    
    def withdraw(self, number, value):
        account = self.get_account(number)
        if account['money'] < value:
            print(f'{self.name} no enought money')
            return False
        
        account['money'] -= value
        account['history'].append(-value)
        account['number_of_withdraws'] += 1
        return True
    
    def transaction_history(self, number):
        account = self.get_account(number)
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        print("You have withdraw", account['number_of_withdraws'] , "On date:" , today)
        print("You have deposit" , account['number_of_deposits']  , "On date:" , today)
        
    def take_loan(self, number):
        account = self.get_account(number)
        answer = int(input("Enter the amount of loan who would you like to take between - 100Euros and 300 Euros: "))
        if answer > 300:
            print("Choose between 100 - 300 Euros not more")
        else:
            print("You have taken out for loan, you will pay extra 1.5 from that sum" , answer * 1.5)

# --- main ---        
        
bank = Bank()
bank.open_account("Bill", 42919502, "Massachutes", 4000)
bank.open_account("John", 30503202104, "Cardiff", 4000)

bank.deposit(42919502, 500)
bank.withdraw(30503202104, 1200)

print('\n===== before =====\n')
bank.show_accounts(show_history=True)

bank.transfer(42919502, 30503202104, 100)
bank.transfer(42919502, 30503202104, 300)
bank.transfer(30503202104, 42919502, 500)

print('\n===== after =====\n')
bank.show_accounts(show_history=True)
```

Result:

```
===== before =====


--- 42919502 ---

Name is:  Bill
Account Number:  42919502
Money:  4500
History: [500]

--- 30503202104 ---

Name is:  John
Account Number:  30503202104
Money:  2800
History: [-1200]

===== after =====


--- 42919502 ---

Name is:  Bill
Account Number:  42919502
Money:  4600
History: [500, -100, -300, 500]

--- 30503202104 ---

Name is:  John
Account Number:  30503202104
Money:  2700
History: [-1200, 100, 300, -500]
```

Comment: I like your logic is a little bit difficult as a begginer but thank you it really help me !

Comment: eventually you could use normal dictonary instead of `Account` to keep data but then you would have to move functions to `Bank` and they would have to get account_number as first arguments - ie. `bank.deposite(42919502, 100)`

Comment: I added example with dictionary instead of `Account`

Comment: Thank you a lot you really helped me! But is it my code good or bad for reading to know if i am on right path and on what should i work to get good logic like you

Comment: code seems OK. I would keep all history on one list with details like date, type of operation (deposit or withdraw) and I would add methods filter by date or  operation. If code works and you want to know if it good then you should rather ask on similar portal [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: can you see my latest post about issue a bill i didn't know how to contact you i think you will see because no one replies if you need any understanding better ask me in comment sorry to contact you in this way!